# How do I merge a previous time series with a following time series in R

Tags: r, merge, time-series

Is it possible to pad a following time series with its preceding time series in R?
The data which I am working on, is time series relative humidity data. The data is not continuous. It has wide inter-annual gap filled by NA. I used the following code to generate the time series separately

```
try.data.ts=ts(try.ts[,2],frequency=30,start=c(1975,1))
try.data.ts1=ts(try.ts1[,2],frequency=30,start=c(1998,1))
```

The observations are only for the month of April.
Then, I used the merge command to combine them together

```
mydata=merge(try.data.ts, try.data.ts1,all=T)
```

however, it end up with unusual length of observation.
Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thank you

Comment: Your code does not work for me. It requires a specific package loaded?

Comment: Need a reproducible example that shows us the form of your data.

Comment: I used "ts" command of stats package. The daily data (relative humidity) is only for the months of April and May. The first time series starts from 1975-1981 and the second time series starts from 1998-2002.